# Deleting element of slice modifies original value

Tags: go, slice

I'm wondering about the following behavior:

```
sl1 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
fmt.Printf("sl1: %v\n", sl1)
//Prints sl1: [0 1 2 3 4 5]

idx := 3
sl2 := append(sl1[:idx], sl1[idx+1:]...)
fmt.Printf("sl1: %v\n", sl1)
//Prints sl1: [0 1 2 4 5 5] -> strange!
fmt.Printf("sl2: %v\n", sl2)
//Prints sl2: [0 1 2 4 5] -> expected!
```

Looks like append is doing something weird on the original slice pointer.
Is this a bug or intended behavior? See also https://play.golang.org/p/EX3eqJz5Q8K

Answer (score 7):

A slice consists of a reference to an underlying array, a length, and a capacity (maximum length). `sl1[:idx]` is a different slice than `sl1` (the length is 3 instead of 6), but the underlying array is the same. The `append` places elements 4 and 5 of `sl1` into the array at positions 3 and 4. `sl2` is then a slice of length 5, but the underlying array is still the original one referenced by `sl1`, so when you print `sl1`, you see that the elements have changed. See https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals for an explanation of how slices work.

Comment: I have an idea of how this works internally. I just didn't expect the side-effects of append. Now I do.